# How to convert an ArrayList<Object> to an ArrayList<Double> in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to convert a List of Objects which contains only numbers such as Doubles and Integers to a new  List which is a List of Double. How can I do that?

```
    List<Object> o = new ArrayList<>();

     example: o contains  o = {1,1.0,3,5.6,7.3};

    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried using the stream() method but no luck there.

Comment: "but no luck there" exactly why?

Comment: What do you mean "convert to an empty variable"?

Comment: Cast it to a raw  `List`:   `(List)`.  This will give you a warning, which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

list = o.stream().filter(t -> t instanceof Double).map(t -> (Double) t).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: What if the Object contains Integers how would I be able to take those values?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use streams - just cast it to a raw `List` like so:

```
List<Object> o = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> list = (List) o;
```

Comment: But using Streams is safe.  This is not.  If the List contains any values which are not Doubles, you will get weird ClassCastException at runtime, in places that appear to have no casts.